# Why the previous data is still got in this code?

Tags: php

I want to get all the filenames inside all subdirectories of a parent directory. Here is the code :

```
$rep = '.';
    if (file_exists($rep))
    {
        $myDirectory = opendir($rep);

        while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory)) {
            $dirArray[] = $entryName;
        }

        closedir($myDirectory);

        $indexCount = count($dirArray);

        sort($dirArray);

        $resultat = "";

        for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) 
        {
            if (substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1) != "." && is_dir($dirArray[$index]) && is_numeric($dirArray[$index]))
            {
                $resultat .= $dirArray[$index].";";     // dossier de photos d'un client

                $repClient = $dirArray[$index];
                $clientDirectory = opendir($repClient);
                while($photoName = readdir($clientDirectory)) 
                {
                    $photoArray[] = $photoName;
                }
                closedir($clientDirectory);

                $photoCount = count($photoArray);

                sort($photoArray);

                for ($img = 0; $img < $photoCount ; $img++)
                {
                    if (substr("$photoArray[$img]", 0, 1) != ".")
                    {
                        $resultat .= $photoArray[$img].";";
                    }
                }
                echo "$resultat<br/>";
            }
        }
    }
```

My problem is that there are actually two subdirectories inside the parent directory , and each of these two subdirectories has only one file ( photo31.png and photo32.png respectively ). When I open the webpage containing this script then I got this output :

```
7455573;photo31.png;
7455573;photo31.png;7455575;photo31.png;photo32.png;
```

So why does the `photo31.png` file is still got in the second line of the output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate answer to your question is: because you do not reset the `$photoArray` variable between iterating over subdirectories. So when you look into the second subdirectory, `$photoArray` still contains the items you put into it when looking into the first subdirectory.

Here (before the `for`) you reset the "result" string:

```
 $resultat = "";
```

You also need to reset `$photoArray`:

```
 $resultat = "";
 $photoArray = array();
```

Apart from this, the code as a whole could definitely use some improvement. You have this code:

```
 $myDirectory = opendir($rep);

 while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory)) {
     $dirArray[] = $entryName;
 }

 closedir($myDirectory);
 $indexCount = count($dirArray);
 sort($dirArray);
```

And then, inside the `for` loop, you have pretty much the same code again (the variable names change, but it's the same). You may want to try making a recursive implementation that calls itself to "go into" a directory instead of manually doing it this way.